# How to say "I see things differently than any others do" in Japanese?

Tags: grammar

I am a Japanese language student in the beginner level. I have just learnt a grammar as follows.

> パンとごはんとどちらの方が好きですか。ごはんの方が好きです。

I am impatient to learn something like,

> I see things differently than any others do.

Could you give me a crash course for this?

Comment: 物事が他の人と違って見える. The _than_ is translated to _と (with)_.

Comment: Agree with Yang Muye's translation. Just a side comment that this generally seems like a very えらそう thing to say, so depending on context, just be wary of how you may come off to others

Comment: -unless you want to say that you tend to have different opinions compared do other people, which sounds much more neutral. 「他の人と別の意見がよくあります」or so. Somebody else can probably translate this 英和 more naturally than I may have just done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Natural ways of saying that would be:

> 「（私**は**）[物]{もの}の[見方]{みかた}**が**ほかの[誰]{だれ}とも[違]{ちが}います。」 or
>
> 「（私**の**）物の見方**は**ほかの人とは違っています。」

Back in high school (in Japan), we would have been "required" to translate it to something like:

> 「（私の）物の見方は,ほかの[人達]{ひとたち}の**それ**とは違います。」

with 「それ」 referring to 「物の見方」.　This sounds a little more formal than the first two sentences above.  The first two are more informal if not necessarily colloquial.